# Write data from pyspark to ElasticSearch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hadoop, elasticsearch, pyspark

I followed this [article](https://prasanthkothuri.wordpress.com/2016/06/17/integrating-hadoop-and-elasticsearch-part-2-querying-and-writing-to-elasticsearch-from-apache-spark/) to send some data to AWS ES, and I used the jar elasticsearch-hadoop. Here is my script:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("WriteToES")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    es_conf = {"es.nodes" : "https://search-elasticsearchdomaine.region.es.amazonaws.com/",
    "es.port" : "9200","es.nodes.client.only" : "true","es.resource" : "sensor_counts/metrics"}
    es_df_p = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("output/part-00000-c353bb29-f189-4189-b35b-f7f1af717355.csv")
    es_df_pf= es_df_p.groupBy("network_key")
    es_df_pf.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='-',
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
    conf=es_conf)
```

Then I run this command line:

```
spark-submit --jars elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.3.1.jar write_to_es.py
```

where write_to_es.py is the script above.

Here is the error I got:

```
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/user/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/output/part-00000-c353bb29-f189-4189-b35b-f7f1af717355.csv:0+178633
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1). 1143 bytes result sent to driver
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 11 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1)
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (load at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) finished in 0,011 s
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: load at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, took 0,018727 s
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 192.168.1.26:39609 in memory (size: 2.1 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on 192.168.1.26:39609 in memory (size: 22.9 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/05/05 17:51:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on 192.168.1.26:39609 in memory (size: 2.1 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/write_to_es.py", line 11, in <module>
    es_df_pf.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
  File "/home/user/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 964, in __getattr__
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile'
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.26:4040
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-501c4efa-5402-430e-93c1-aaff4caddef0
17/05/05 17:51:53 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-501c4efa-5402-430e-93c1-aaff4caddef0/pyspark-52406fa8-e8d1-4aca-bcb6-91748dc87507
```

How to solve this:

```
 AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile'
```

Any help or suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.

After reading [this article](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-in-apache-spark-python), I found the answer!!!

You have to convert to `PythonRDD` Type like this:

```
>>> type(df)
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

>>> type(df.rdd)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>

>>> df.rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(...) # Got the same error message

>>> df.printSchema() # My schema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 ...

# Let's convert to PythonRDD
>>> python_rdd = df.map(lambda item: ('key', {
... 'id': item['id'],
    ...
... }))

>>> python_rdd
PythonRDD[42] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43

>>> python_rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(...) # Now, success
```

Comment: What's the difference between `PythonRDD` and `RDD`? Why `RDD` raises the error but not `PythonRDD`?

Answer (score 0):

saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile is in RDD ,

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD

I guess this line should be

```
es_df_pf.rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile
```

Comment: When I tried it, it gave me a huge error : `17/05/09 09:40:21 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for pyspark.sql.types._create_row)`