# Writing to elasticsearch indexes dynamically via pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I have a pyspark DataFrame like this:

```
my_df = spark.read.load("some-parquet-path")
```

I'd like to be able to write it out to some elasticsearch indexes dynamically based on the contents of the "id" column in my DataFrame. I tried doing this:

```
my_df.write.format(
    "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql"
).mode('overwrite').options(**conf).save("my_index_{id}/my_type")
```

But I get:

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: no such index
```

How can I do this?

**Update**

This seems to work when I change the mode from 'overwrite' to 'append'. It would be great to have an explanation of why that is the case...

Comment: Not an expert on this, but given the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html) you might actually prefer to switch to a RDD to write to ES, such as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43949032/4121573)

Comment: Would you care adding some information about your spark and es clusters ? Also which version of the connector you are using ?